# PHP Unsubscribe Script with Hash

Tags: php

I created a PHP unsubscribe script with hash:

```
<?php
    $email_addr = "myemail@mydomain.com";
    $confirmation = hash("sha256", 'mysalt' . $email_addr . 'moresalt');
    $link = "unsubscribe.php?id=$email_addr&validation_hash=$confirmation";
    echo 'Do you really want to unsubscribe?<br><br>';
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Yes. I want to unsubscribe!</a>';
?>
```

What the backend (unsubscribe.php) do is pretty common: login the mysql database, check if this user is a active subscriber. Unsubscribe him if yes.

Can a attacker doing a nasty loop using curl (or something similar) to crack the validation hash? Or maybe can a attacker bring down the website by doing the endless loop?

Thank you.

Comment: For what purpose are you adding the validation hash...?

Comment: Attacker can try and do a lot of things, there isn't a magic php trick that will make your website 100% hacker-free. I think that what you did is sufficient for protecting your unsubscribing logic

Comment: @deceze, validation hash it there so that nobody can unregister all the subcribers with a nasty loop. But as seen on my questions, I'm not sure :P

Comment: You say that unsubscribe.php already requires the user to be logged in, and supposedly the user could only unregister themselves to begin with... no?

Comment: @AlonEitan, do you think a endless loop using curl (or similiar) will bring the site down because the unsubscribe.php will be pushed to login to the mysql database many time in such a short period?

Comment: @deceze, the user dont need to be logged in first. He clicked the link from a newsletter and that unsubscribe page displayed. He need to click on the "yes, I want to unsubscribe!" link to do a final unsubscribe.

Comment: Well, on my server i've installed [ModSecurity](https://www.modsecurity.org/) (and some other stuff I don't currently remember) for protection, so it blocks the users before they even get to the PHP level

Comment: A [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack is always a concern, completely unspecific to this particular unsubscription script. You need to worry about that in a bigger context, not locally for this one thing.

Comment: So what does the link in the mail look like?

Comment: @deceze, the link in the mail look like this: http://example.com/u.php?id=myemail@mydomain.com&validation_hash=e483714ab54aa7322e8b36356aaab5af1f78883f5312f21972448429fc03a92d

Comment: @AlonEitan, I will take a look at ModSecurity, maybe it already installed too on my server :) Thanks!

Comment: So the link in the mail already contains the same validation hash...? Otherwise I might have an appropriate link for you... https://twitter.com/old_sound/status/602996592531091456

Comment: @deceze, yes, the link in the mail already contains the same validation hash. The twitter link, I'm not sure if I'm understanding you :P They are contain same validation hash because I want the subscriber click on the final link to do the unsubscription and he don't need to be logged in.

Answer (score 4):

So what's needed to successfully unsubscribe is:

1. the email address
2. the hash, which consists of:

   1. the email address
   2. a static salt

Obviously the first part of that hash is redundant, which leaves the second: the static salt. This is the same value for everyone. Every hash is calculated with the same value. If that value ever became publicly known, all your security would vanish and anyone could unsubscribe anyone.

How might the salt become know publicly?

1. successful attacks against your server (at which point you probably have way bigger problems already)
2. data leaks in various ways (bugs, process issues with backups, stupidity, many other reasons)
3. guessing

Let's take a better look at that last one: an attacker could go through the subscription/unsubscription process themselves to obtain a hash for a known email address. So they have one of two parts of what makes up the hash. The SHA family of hashes is specifically *fast*, so the attacker could simply try a whole bunch of salt values until they found the same hash that you're using. At that point they know the salt...

So, yeah, not the best implementation.

Rather generate one ***completely random*** value (read from `/dev/urandom` or such) which you store with the email address in the database and use that as validation <del>hash</del> token. This value has no connection to any other data and cannot be brute-forced offline. This leaves the attacker only with the possibility of an *online* attack (actually trying to request many many URLs one after the other), which is orders of magnitude slower, making it infeasible; and it allows you to additionally slow the attacker down or block them outright if you detect such an attack.

Comment: make sense, this is a very good explanation, thank you! Unfortunetely I'm just a wanna be coder and my first PHP script was written few days ago by following step by step tutorial I found online :(

What I'm trying to said is although security is my concern, database will be hastle for now. Afterall, when the server compromised, shouldn't the completely random value stored in database also will not save us?

For sure it will slower the attacker when trying to bruteforce, which is good.

Comment: Without database, is there anyway to improve the script? Again, my concern is attacker can unregister all the subscribers and/or bring the site down when trying to bruteforce using endless loop.

Thanks!

Comment: If your database is breached it's more or less game over anyway; you've got other things to worry about then. Replace "database" with "wherever you're currently storing your emails". I assume you have a list of emails *somewhere* that you're modifying/unsubscribing from...?! Or is your script just sending an email to someone who does the actual work?

Comment: actually I have a database of subscribers stored in the mysql database, but this is created and maintained by a mailing list software. I dont create the database/table myself. The mailing list software has it's own unsubscribe link/system, but right now I need to email from another application other then the mailing list software interface, so I need my own unsubcription link :)

Comment: Well, then you're in a bit of a bind... you could be putting up your own database with a copy of the registered emails and somehow keep that in sync... which is probably not something you'll want to do. Then what I say stands, and the only things to really improve are: 1) choose an extremely long and entirely random static salt which is virtually impossible to guess, 2) use a **slow** hash like bcrypt. These two steps together make it less feasible for someone to successfully attack your system in the way described above.

Comment: again a very good advice. I'm going to follow your lastest advice: using an extremely long and entirely random salt and bcrypt. Thanks a lot! :)